# Fast adding random variables in C++

Tags: c++, performance, random

**Short version**: how to most efficiently represent and add two random variables given by lists of their realizations?

**Mildly longer version:**
for a workproject, I need to add several random variables each of which is given by a list of values. For example, the realizations of rand. var. A are {1,2,3} and the realizations of B are {5,6,7}. Hence, what I need is the distribution of A+B, i.e. {1+5,1+6,1+7,2+5,2+6,2+7,3+5,3+6,3+7}. And I need to do this kind of adding several times (let's denote this number of additions as COUNT, where COUNT might reach 720) for different random variables (C, D, ...).

**The problem:** if I use this stupid algorithm of summing each realization of A with each realization of B, the complexity is exponential in COUNT. Hence, for the case where each r.v. is given by three values, the amount of calculations for COUNT=720 is 3^720 ~ 3.36xe^343 which will last till the end of our days to calculate:) Not to mention that in real life, the lenght of each r.v. is gonna be 5000+.

**Solutions:**
1/ The first solution is to use the fact that I am OK with rounding, i.e. having integer values of realizations. Like this, I can represent each r.v. as a vector and for at the index corresponding to a realization I have a value of 1 (when the r.v. has this realization once). So for a r.v. A and a vector of realizations indexed from 0 to 10, the vector representing A would be [0,1,1,1,0,0,0...] and the representation for B would be [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,10]. Now I create A+B by going through these vectors and do the same thing as above (sum each realization of A with each realization of B and codify it into the same vector structure, quadratic complexity in vector length). The upside of this approach is that the complexity is bound. The problem of this approach is that in real applications, the realizations of A will be in the interval [-50000,50000] with a granularity of 1. Hence, after adding two random variables, the span of A+B gets to -100K, 100K.. and after 720 additions, the span of SUM(A, B, ...) gets to [-36M, 36M] and even quadratic complexity (compared to exponential complexity) on arrays this large will take forever.

2/ To have shorter arrays, one could possibly use a hashmap, which would most likely reduce the number of operations (array accesses) involved in A+B as the assumption is that some non-trivial portion of the theoreical span [-50K, 50K] will never be a realization. However, with continuing summing of more and more random variables, the number of realizations increases exponentially while the span increases only linearly, hence the density of numbers in the span increases over time. And this would kill the hashmap's benefits.

So the question is: how can I do this problem efficiently? The solution is needed for calculating a VaR in electricity trading where all distributions are given empirically and are like no ordinary distributions, hence formulas are of no use, we can only simulate.

---

Using math was considered as the first option as half of our dept. are mathematicians. However, the distributions that we're going to add are badly behaved and the COUNT=720 is an extreme. More likely, we are going to use COUNT=24 for a daily VaR. Taking into account the bad behaviour of distributions to add, for COUNT=24 the central limit theorem would not hold too closely (the distro of SUM(A1, A2, ..., A24) would not be close to normal). As we're calculating possible risks, we'd like to get a number as precise as possible.

The intended use is this: you have hourly casflows from some operation. The distribution of cashflows for one hour is the r.v. A. For the next hour, it's r.v. B, etc. And your question is: what is the largest loss in 99 percent of cases? So you model the cashflows for each of those 24 hours and add these cashflows as random variables so as to get a distribution of the total casfhlow over the whole day. Then you take the 0.01 quantile.

Comment: I think your complexity calculation is wrong, it should be 720^3 and not 3^720.

Comment: @Skizz. When I have A={1,2,3}, B={4,5,6} the resulting A+B distro takes 3*3 integer additions. The result is {4,5,6,8,10,12,12,15,18}. To add another r.v. C={7,8,9}, I have 9*3 integer additions. Hence, each added r.v. increases the number of integer additions three times.

Comment: @DanBencik you just multiplied...  I thought you were supposed to add.

Comment: I see now, the problem is beggining to makes sense now.

Comment: @paddy: You are right. So A+B should be {5,6,7,6,7,8,7,8,9}. My apologies.

Comment: So you're interested in the distribution.  Doesn't that mean you just have {5,6,7,8,9} with a frequency of {1,2,3,2,1}?  Are you always working with contiguous sets?  You said they were random, but then it seemed they might be linearly increasing with granularity 1.  In that case you could easily compute the range and then use convolution to calculate the frequencies.

Comment: @paddy "all distributions are given empirically and are like no ordinary distributions"

Comment: I think this question would be better on the Math StackExchange site.

Comment: It's not just ~3.36xe^343 calculations in the worst case, but ~3.36xe^343 values - that's a heck of a lot storage.

Comment: @Skizz: As paddy said, Im interested in distributions so when you add two r.v.s which are spanned over [-X, X] then span of the sum increases to [-2X,2X], however the number of calculations is (2X)^2. The storage simply increases linearly. Thanks for the link to Match StachExchange!

Comment: @paddy: Thanks. Does this convolution have any specific name? All I know is the convolution matrix from neural networks and that seems to have nothing to do with r.v. additions:) Or maybe I just dont know what you mean by convolution.

Comment: So can you confirm that you want to know what happens to the distribution of values when each set can be considered to be uniform (*ie* consecutive integers in a range)?  If that's the case I can provide an answer that might be useful.

Comment: @paddy: Im sorry but the distributions are by no means uniform. I appreciate the effort though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two methods. An approximative one and an exact one...

**Approximative method** models the sum of random variables by a lot of samplings. Basically, having random variables `A`, `B` we randomly sample from each r.v. 50K times, add the sampled values (here SSE can help a lot) and we have a distribution of `A+B`. This is how mathematicians would do this in Mathematica.

**Exact method** utilizes something Dan Puzey proposed, namely summing only some small portion of each r.v.'s density. Let's say we have random variables with the following "densities" (where each value is of the same likelihood for simplicity sake)

```
A = {-5,-3,-2}
B = {+0,+1,+2}
C = {+7,+8,+9}
```

The sum of `A+B+C` is going to be

```
{2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9}
```

and if I want to know the whole distribution precisely, I have no other choice than summing each elem of A with each elem of B and then each elem of this sum with each elem of C. However, if I only want the 99% VaR of this sum, i.e. 1% percentile of this sum, I only have to sum the smallest elements of `A,B,C`.

More precisely, I will take `nA,nB,nC` smallest elements from each distribution. To determine `nA,nB,nC` let's set these to 1 first. Then, increase `nA` by one if `A[nA] = min( A[nA], B[nB], C[nC])` (counting on that `A,B,C` are sorted). This way, I can get the `nA, nB, nC` smallest elements of `A,B,C` which I will have to sum together (each with each other) and take the X-th smallest sum (where X is 1% multiplied by total combination count of sums, i.e. 3*3*3 for `A,B,C`). This also tells when to stop increasing `nA,nB,nC` - stop when `nA*nB*nC` > X.

However, like this I am doing the same redundancy again, i.e. I am calculating the whole distribution of `A+B+C` left of the 1% percentile. Even this will be MUCH shorter than calculating the whole distro of `A+B+C`, however. But I believe there should be a simple iterative algo to tell exaclty the the given VaR number in `O(a*b)` where `a` is the number of added r.v.s and `b` is the max number of elements in the density of each r.v.

I will be glad for any comments on whether I am correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce the number of passes required to make the whole addition, possibly reducing it to a single pass for every list, including the final one.

I don't think you can cut down on the total number of additions.

In addition, you should look into parallel algorithms and multithreading, if applicable.

At this point, most processors are able to perform additions in parallel, given proper instrucions ([SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions)), which will make the additions many times faster(still not a cure for the complexity problem).

Comment: Sure, instead of adding 720 times, I would add log(720)/log(2) times in a tree-like adding scheme. But as you said, it does not solve the complexity problem. As for SSE, i would love to use it but so far I can't see where to apply it to as for representations indexed from 0 to 5 you don't have for A=[0,1,0,0,0] and B=[0,0,1,0,0] that A+B is represented like [0,1,1,0,0]. Instead, A+B is [0,0,0,1,0,0]. That's why part of my question is how to represent these random variables most efficiently (possibly to allow the use of SSE). But many thanks anyway!!

Comment: You *can* reduce the total number of additions, from the description in the question.  See my answer!

Comment: @Dan: For sure I am going to do that!

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your question, you're going to need an awful lot of computation to get the exact answer. So it's not going to happen.

However, as you're dealing with random values, it would be possible to apply some mathmatics to the problem. Wouldn't the result of all these additions result in something that approaches the normal distribution? For example, consider rolling a single dice. Each number has equal probability so the realisations don't follow a normal distribution (actually, they probably do, there was a program on BBC4 last week about it and it showed that lottery balls had a normal distribution to their appearance). However, if you roll two dice and sum them, then the realisations do follow a normal distribution. So I think the result of your computation is going to approximate a normal distribution so it becomes a problem of finding the average value and the sigma value for a given set of inputs. You can workout the upper and lower bounds for each input as well as their averages and I'm sure a bit of Googling will provide methods for applying functions to normal distributions.

I guess there is a corollary question and that is what the results are used for? Knowing how the results are used will inform the decision on how the results are created.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the programmatic solutions, you can cut down the total number of additions quite significantly as your data set grows.

If we define four groups `W`, `X`, `Y` and `Z`, each with three elements, by your own maths this leads to a large number of operations:

- W + X => 9 operations
- (W + X) + Y => 27 operations
- (W + X + Y) + Z => 81 operations
- **TOTAL: 117 operations**

However, if we assume a strictly-ordered definition of your "add" operation so that two sets `{a,b}` and `{c,d}` always result in `{a+c,a+d,b+c,b+d}` then your operation is *[associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associativity)*.  That means that you can do this:

- W + X => 9 operations
- Y + Z => 9 operations
- (W + X) + (Y + Z) => 81 operations
- **TOTAL: 99 operations**

This is a saving of 18 operations, for a simple case.  If you extend the above to 6 groups of 3 members, the total number of operations can be dropped from 1089 to 837 - almost 20% saving.  This improvement is more pronounced the more data you have (more sets or more elements will give more savings).

Further, this opens the problem to better parallelisation: if you have 200 groups to process, you can start by combining the 100 pairs in parallel, then the 50 pairs or results, then 25, etc.  This will allow a large degree of parallelism that should give you much better performance.  (For example, 720 sets would be added in ~10 parallel operations as each parallel add will allow increasing `COUNT` by a factor of 2.)

I'm absolutely no expert on this, but it would seem an ideal problem for using the parallel procesing capability of a typical GPU - my understanding is that something like CUDA would make short work of processing all these calculations in parallel.

**EDIT:** If your real question is "what's your largest loss" then this is a much easier problem.  Given that every value in the ultimate set is the sum of one value from each "component" set, your biggest loss will generally be found by combining the *lowest* value from each component set.  Finding these lower values (one value per set) is a much simpler job, and you then only need sum together that limited set of values.

Comment: Thank you! I mentioned the parralelism in reply to jt234's answer. However, it's exactly the programmatic solutions that determine wheter I can use something like SSE or CUDA.

Comment: I *think* the solution I've described there would suit CUDA perfectly.  However, my last edit is worth considering too, if all you're doing is finding the lower limits of the overall range.

Comment: The problem is a bit more complicated. Im not trying to find the worst case of all. For X being the total amount of possible outcomes, I'm trying to find the 0.01*X-th worst outcome.

Comment: Well if, for example, you took the two lowest values from each of `n` groups, you would have the `2^n` lowest values (you could take the lowest 3 of each set if that's not enough).  You can easily calculate the total number of values based on the number of groups and count of each group.  So, you only need to calculate the sums of these lower values to answer your problem - still orders of magnitude easier than calculating every possible value.

Comment: Dan, I'm not sure whether this relies on the added distros having appeoximately the same range. Imagine A={-50K, 10K} and B={-10K;40K}. If you take `n` smallest values from each distribution and add them, you cannot be sure that what you end up with is going to be `n^2` smallest values from the A+B distribution. Or am I overseeing something? Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: Each combination of additions can (by your explanation) only contain a single value from each set.  For example: your combination of `A` and `B` can *never* be `50K + 10K`, because both of those values are from `A`.  So yes, you can be sure of that, because if you have *any* value from `A + {any other set}` that included the `50k` from `A`, you can get a smaller value by taking the `10k` instead.  NOTE: you do have to take *the same `n` values from each distribution*, and sort those, and then take your required number - but this is still massively smaller than your original calculation.

Comment: Dan, what I am getting at is this. Imagine I want the 50% lowest numbers of A+B+C and A={-5,-4,-3}, B={-1,0,2}, C={2,4,6}. In advance, you have no clue which numbers are going to be the lowest 50% of the A+B+C sum. Specifically, the lower 50% of A+B+C is {-4,-3,-3,-2,-2,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0} and in all of these results you add the WHOLE r.v. A with elements of B and C. So if you cut the largest number of A off, you are going to inflate the resulting 50% of lowest values.